# Laptop Shuts Down Without Battery Warning

Tags: windows-7, battery

I have a windows 7 professional compaq laptop.

It shuts down automatically when the battery is depleted - without warning.

I keep loosing all my work ...

How can I correct this so it gives a warning before it shuts down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Control Panel->Power Options->Change Plan Settings->Change Advanced Power Settings
2. Go to Battery->Critical battery action and then set what you need. Also try setting the Low Battery Notification to On.

Comment: +1. And if this doesn't work, it might be time to get a new battery.

Comment: @Randolph: Yeah. Either that, or do something I like to do every few months: Turn off all low-battery actions, then drain the laptop battery until it reaches 0%. Chances are, if your battery has lost around 50% or more of its capacity, you'll notice that it'll stay at 0% for quite a long time (I've seen someone's laptop do this for an hour or two)... then just use it again, and it'll revive the battery most of the time. :)

Comment: Battery is quite worn, I bet this is exactly what is happening

Comment: @rlb.usa: Yeah, I think draining it completely will help. But be careful to *not* do that very often, or it'll do more harm than good. (Once every 4-6 months should be reasonable.)